# Python, shared library, ctypes

Tags: python

Пытаюсь перенести проект на Ubuntu. Проект - OpenGL сценка.

Под Windows было все просто: я писал код opengl на С, в dev-C++ создавал dll, кидал в папку с проектом и подгружал ее self.clib = cdll.LoadLibrary('clib/clib.dll').

Как создавать .so под ubuntu я разобрался, но как ее подключить? Проблема в том, что если я захочу дать кому-то свою программу, то ему придется эту библиотеку самостоятельно включать в глобальный путь поиска библиотек. 
Можно ли, shared library использовать как dll, или же средствами питона включить ее в путь поиска? В общем, чтобы это все сама программа делала?

Comment: А установка LD_PRELOAD не помогает?

Comment: Да я уже разобрался) То о чем ты говоришь - это и есть прописывания глобальных путей поиска.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кому понадобиться, нужно прописывать просто глобальный путь, то есть /home/user/ololo/.../clib.so